# Rounding returned float values from a DB to their 'correct' values

Tags: sql, floating-point, sybase

I've got a database column that contains (for some reason lost in the midst of time) float values.

So, someone populates a DB table with some small value, say 0.00025, and when I run a report I actually get back 0.000249999999....or somesuch, due to the inability to represent the entered value.

Is there any reliable way to take the float value and convert back to what was originally entered?

DB is Sybase.

Comment: have you tried round function? :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reliable way to take the
>   float value and convert back to what
>   was originally entered?

No. There are roughly, ummm, a boat load of real values that might map to a single floating-point value. The db stores the closest FP approximation to the original entry; there are, in the general case, an infinite number of real values for which 0.000249999999... is the closest FP approximation.

And again, in the general case, you can't safely make assumptions about the length of the entry. That is, you can't safely tell by looking at 0.000249999999 whether the user typed that in within an application program, whether the user typed .00025, whether a dba updated that column to the result of a calculation (in which case the "original" value might be less than 0.0002499999etc) and so on and so on.

But, if you know how many digits you want to see to the right of the decimal point, you can use Sybase's ROUND() function.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the behavior of floating-point numbers (you sacrifice accuracy for capacity or efficiency). While you can use rounding to achieve approximations, if you require exact storage up to a particular level of precision, you should use `decimal`.

Comment: No, that's not the question that was asked: it looks like this developer needs to back out the Float error with a ROUND() function. And 'go back and rebuild the database' is a deeply unhelpful answer for developers working against a database owned by a DBA on another continent who will point out - correctly - that production databased in use by dozens of applications and thousands of users don't get rebuilt because a developer can't get a good answer off StackOverflow about recovering the 'drift' in a float.

Comment: @Nile: The original value is lost. The question says he wants to return it to the original value that was entered, and that is (in a general sense) not possible. For his *specific example*, he could simply round to five decimal places and he would retrieve a value that is the same as what was entered, but there isn't a way to do this in a general sense (which is what was asked). Of course I understand the design decision may be outside of the developer's control, but that does not change the accuracy or correctness of the answer (as inconvenient as that might be).

Answer (score 0):

That would be 0.0002498626708984375....

This comes down to "Know your data". How do you know that the correct value was not 0.0002498626708984375?  Likely because you know how many decimals it was originally specified to.

Use that knowledge to solve the problem, by casting to NUMERIC(8, 5) or whatever the appropriate solution is.