# SQL field type field not shows up

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]I have a MySQL table in which one of the fields is `variation` and type is `float`. Its value is `0.2`. But when I query like `WHERE variation = '0.2'` it is not showing the result, instead it returns null. What I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_products
  WHERE frequency BETWEEN '2' AND '3'
    AND gain = '2'
    AND gain_variation = '0.2'
    AND noise = '2'
    AND power = '10'
```

Comment: Does your table have a row that satisfies your entire `WHERE` clause? Please show us the row(s) you're expecting as a result.

Comment: I have updated my question. Plz check

Comment: Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260903/rounding-returned-float-values-from-a-db-to-their-correct-values

Comment: And a must read: **http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html**

Comment: If you want to store values without floating-point arithmetix but with fixed precision, use `DECIMAL(x,y)` datatype.

Comment: If you have to use floats, then your equality checks should be converted from `a=b` to `ABS(a-b) < 1.0e-5` (you can have smaller or bigger precision, using other than 5 constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the number a try again.

eg `WHERE variation = 0.2`

Edit: As Peeka pointed out, the quotes don't matter in MySQL.

Are you absolutely sure the value of the float is exactly 0.2 and there aren't significant digits that are getting rounded? Can you try using `BETWEEN 0.19 AND 0.21` and seeing whether the row you're after gets returned (I know it's not an equivalent query and may return unwanted results but it will test whether the value is exactly 0.2 or whether it's rounded in the client).

**Edit 2**: I'd wager it's because of the way MySQL stores floats - taken from their manual:

> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value represented internally.

See here for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

It is recommended to use a range to filter instead of an equality, so if you use `BETWEEN 0.19 AND 0.21` do you get the result you want?

Comment: The quotes shouldn't be a problem, at least not if the database used is mysql.

Comment: @Nitish: Can you post your entire query? Are you sure that your regional settings use the decimal point (not a , for example)?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE frequency BETWEEN '2' AND '3' AND gain = '2' AND gain_variation = '0.2' AND noise = '2' AND power = '10'

Comment: @Nitish: Have you tried removing *all* of the quotes? eg `SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE frequency BETWEEN 2 AND 3 AND gain = 2 AND gain_variation = 0.2 AND noise = 2 AND power = 10` - I know you're using MySQL but just to rule things out...

Comment: I just created a test table and queried it with quotes. @Nitish are you 100% sure you have a row matching your criteria? Can you show the data the row has?

Comment: @Nitish: Does it work if you use `gain_variation BETWEEN 0.19 AND 0.21`? Just wondering whether there are significant figures at play.

Comment: @mwan yes mwan...its working perfectly if I remove `gain_variation = 0.2`

Comment: @Pekka plz see my table image

Comment: @Nitish: Check out my Edit2 above

Comment: I think @mwan nailed it re: floats. If you change it to `gain_variation >= 0.2` it shows the row in question but if you chane it to `gain_variation <= 0.2` it doesn't. http://sqlize.com/zTgywJZbPP

Comment: Ok it works . But it wont solve my problem ! Because what if gain_variation = 0.3, it will show in the result set but I am looking for gain_variation with 0.2 only !

Comment: @Nitish: No it won't. Read my edit. Use `gain_variation BETWEEN 0.19 AND 0.21` - if you want it even more precise, use `BETWEEN 0.199 AND 0.201`. Neither of those will return 0.3.

Comment: @Nitish - This is quite a complicated question and the answer can be different depending on which version of MySql you are using, and on what platform.  You perhaps need to do a little reading.  See my link and mwan's

Comment: @mwan Thanks . I declare two vars `$gv1 = $info[gain_var] - 0.0001;` and `$gv2 = $info[gain_var] + 0.0001;` and modified the query to `gain_variation BETWEEN '$gv1' AND '$gv2'` and its working now . Thnks again mwan.

Comment: @Nitish: Good solution. No problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per the discussion on @mwan's answer, consider using an `INT` for this field instead of `FLOAT`. When you `INSERT` a row you can multiply by a certain power of ten (depending on the level of precision you need), and when you `SELECT` you can divide by the same power of ten, but since the field is an `INT` you can always be confident that your `WHERE` clause will match the correct rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_products` (
  frequency             INT,
  gain                  INT,
  gain_variation_x100   INT,  # give it a name that will remind you
  noise                 INT,
  power                 INT
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_products` VALUES
  ('1', '2', '0.2' * 100, '2', '10'),
  ('2', '2', '0.2' * 100, '2', '10'),
  ('2', '2', '0.5' * 100, '2', '10')
  #                ↑
  #                 `---- multiply here
;

SELECT *, ROUND(gain_variation_x100 / 100, 1) AS gain_variation
  FROM tbl_products  #              ^---.  ^---- show 1 digit of precision
  WHERE frequency BETWEEN '2' AND '3' #  \
    AND gain = '2'                    #   `----- divide here
    AND gain_variation_x100 = ROUND('0.2' * 100)
    AND noise = '2'  #                    ^----- multiply here
    AND power = '10'
;
```

You can see this working here: http://sqlize.com/829275n1Fc

Answer (score 0):

This explains it

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-examples.html